# Translation of a curve using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a curve and at `x=900`. My curve should cut the x-axis (`y=0`). However, it does not pass through the x-axis at `x=900`. So I need to translate this curve by removing the error at `x=900`.

I don't have the equation of the curve but I do have the array for y. I have tried the following, but it is not working:

```
RR=[]

for i in range (0,len(x)):
    if x[i]==900:
    E = y[i]
print(E)

for i in range (len(x)):
    RR[i]=y[i]-E
```

I'm getting: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range on line RR[i]=y[i]-E`

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working? Is it giving you an exception? If so, please include the traceback. Is it running OK, but giving you the wrong results?

Comment: im having IndexError: list assignment index out of range on line E=y[i]

Comment: If you are getting the error on _that_ line, then your `x` and `y` lists do not have the same size. Also, please fix your indentation.

Comment: I got the correct answer for E. thanks. But now i need to remove E for all (x,y). The problem now is that i need to substract a number from all values in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `RR` array is empty, so there is no element at position `i` to assign to.

Instead, you can either `append` to the list...

```
RR = []
for i in range (len(x)):
    RR.append(y[i]-E)
```

... or (better) use a list comprehension to construct `RR` from `y`:

```
RR = [yi - E for yi in y]
```

---

Alternatively, you might consider using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/). Assuming `x` and `y` are `numpy.array`s, you can just do `RR = y - y[x==900]` to substract from each item in `y` that value of `y` where `x==900`.